# Attainable through aural practice

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there an adjective meaning *attainable through aural practice*?
As in "This language skill is more easily attainable through aural practice." That is, the more you listen, the more that skill develops.
Is there a single word you could put in the blank in "This is a/an ...... skill"

Comment: If you're referring to a situation where someone plays on the piano and you write the notes down, why not just use your own term, [*aural skills*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ear_training)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider ***[auditory](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/auditory)***

(adj.)

> perceived through or resulting from the sense of hearing

[Dictionary.com]

**Example**

> This skill involves ***auditory*** learning

Comment: That sounds a good one to me. What about "attainable through oral practice"? Do you know of a word?!

Comment: I'd suppose "oral practice" would ideally mean "a lot of speaking". You can use "[oratorical skills](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/oratorical)", but note that it is associated with *public speaking* and not just the act of speaking.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using [**acoustic**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/acoustic?q=acoustic+) which means:

> Relating to sound or the sense of hearing:

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Your example:

> This language skill is more easily attainable through **acoustic**
>   training.

Actual usage:

> [Acoustic
>   training](http://www.thestar.com.my/lifestyle/health/2014/10/07/acoustic-training-could-accelerate-language-skills-early-on-in-babies/)
>   could accelerate language skills early on in babies... This is one of their key jobs, as between 4 and 7 months of age they are setting up their pre-linguistic **acoustic** maps.

Answer (score 1):

This might fit...

a skill learnable by an **osmotic** process.

> **osmosis**
> /ɒzˈməʊsɪs; ɒs-/
> noun
>
> 1.the passage of a solvent through a semipermeable membrane from a less concentrated to a more concentrated solution until both solutions are of the same concentration
>
> 2.diffusion through any membrane or porous barrier, as in dialysis.
>
> 3. **gradual or unconscious assimilation or adoption, as of ideas**

Comment: While the word may be appropriate for OP's context, more often than not, people would tend to associate osmosis with a chemical process, rather than hearing.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

**[Audile](http://tfd.com/audile)**:

> - of, pertaining to, or affecting the auditory nerves or the sense of hearing.
> - oriented to or relying heavily on the faculty of hearing.

**[Auricular](http://tfd.com/auricular)**:

> - Of or relating to the sense of hearing or the organs of hearing.
> - Perceived by or spoken into the ear: an auricular confession.

Answer (score 1):

I may use ***[listening](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Listening) skill:***

> - listening is the conscious processing of the auditory stimuli that have been perceived through hearing.

(Wikipedia)